# Can Nokia Web Tools access device API?

Tags: series-40

I'm using Nokia Web Tools to develop an web app, but I need to access device api such as the model name, for exampl Nokia Asha 301, or E72, etc. Is it possible? If not, is it possible to get the device name through pure regular javascript API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not, except location, but again, location api is in HTML 5, so not really